# Extracting image from web using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use R to extract player photos from the PGA website. The following is my attempt at getting the image URLs, but it does not show the images or the image is blank as shown in the image below.

```
if(!require(pacman))install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load('rvest', 'stringi', 'dplyr', 'tidyr', 'measurements', 'reshape2','foreach','doParallel','curl','httr','Iso','stringi','janitor')

PGA_url <- "https://www.pgatour.com"
pga_web=read_html(paste0(PGA_url,'/players.html'))
plyers_photo <- pga_web%>%html_nodes("[class='player-card']")%>%html_nodes('div.player-image-wrapper')%>%html_nodes('img')%>%html_attr('src')
```

[image]

Could someone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you examine the page source you will see that you are retrieving the content as per the page source i.e. where there is a default `img` value. Scan across and you may notice that there is a `data-src` attribute adjacent which has an alternate ending for the png of the form matching regex: `headshots_\d{5}\.png`.

[image]

When JavaScript runs in the browser, which doesn't happen with an xmlhttp request through rvest, those urls are dynamically updated with the default png endings replaced with those in the `data-src` attributes.

Either replace the endings you are getting with that attribute's value, for the set-size small image, or instead, use the part up to and including `upload` as a base, and combine that with the extracted `data-src` values to give large images.

There is also no need for all those chained `html_nodes()` calls. A single call with an appropriate css selector list will do. Also, prefer the maintained `html_elements()` method, over the old `html_nodes()`:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

PGA_url <- "https://www.pgatour.com"
pga_web <- read_html(paste0(PGA_url, "/players.html"))
placeholder_link <- 'https://pga-tour-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/'

plyers_photo <- pga_web %>%
  html_elements(".player-card .player-image-wrapper img") %>%
  html_attr("data-src") %>% paste0(placeholder_link, .)
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr, hope you are doing well. If you are using excel 2019, I wish to know what happens when you click on the button in the following excel workbook? I'm using excel 2016 and I get some tabular content along with a number in a message box when I run the macro. Here is the [workbook](https://filebin.varnish-software.com/pbam7cov8gov0ht0)

Comment: Invalid use of null. lastPage needs to be declared as `Dim lastPage As mshtml.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`  @SIM